# Trouble controlling the loops

Tags: php

If pressed delet , All images are deleted ,I do not want that.
I just want to delete one image.

```
$get_img = "SELECT * FROM img";
$run_img = mysqli_query($db,$get_img);

while ($row_img= mysqli_fetch_array($run_img)){
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $delete= "DELETE FROM img WHERE id = {$row_img['id']} ";
        $query = mysqli_query ($db , $delete);
    } 

    echo '
        <div style="width:200px; height:200px;  border: 5px solid red; margin:10px; float: right;">
            <img src="images/'.$row_pro['c_img'].'" width="200" height="200" /><br />
            <form action="get.php" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" name="delet" value="delet" />
            </form> 
        </div> 
    ';      
}
```

Comment: First Where did you define `$row_pro['id']` i think its `$row_img['id']` and `$row_pro['c_img']` Too,  and second you must use WHERE in first query like `WHERE img_id='$id'` and define `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: Because you're call delete in a while. That means you're deleting each item.

Comment: Mohammed Alhanafi  , m3lsh ana mesh 3aref english koyas fa msh 3aerf a3

Comment: Mohammed Alhanafi  , klamk tmam $row_img['id'] ,
ana almoshkela 3nde eny asta5demt while fe 3rd el img , f3ayz a7t t7t kol sora botm delete y7zef bs elsora ele howa t7tha . bs ana 7ato goa el while fa bya7zf kol el img ....

Comment: هلا مصطفى، بتقدر الاسهل إلك انه تسوي الحذف بيتم عن طريق الاي دي إذا بدك بسويلك كود يشرحلك الطريقة الحين!

Comment: Mohammed Alhanafi  .... ياريت لحسن انا ضايع جدا في موضوع الصور لا عارف ارسل للداتا بيز ولا عارف استقبل واحذف 
سويلي كود فية insert , get ,delete 
وليك كل الشكر والاحترام

Comment: مصطفي مش فاهم بالزبط إلي بدك اياه، مهو إذا بدك تسوي إضافة حيكون لازمك تسجيل دخول وتسجيل عضويات، وغير هيك اضافة الصور بده شغل شوية لأنه بده زيادة في الحماية، مش لعبة، إذا ناوي تسوي سكربت رفع بسيط استخدم كليجا احسنلك ، الحين بقدر اسويلك الحذف شوي وبكون جاهز

Comment: تمام .... وللعلم انا لسا بتعلم يعني بفهم بس الموضوع ماشي ازاي ميهمنيش الحماية حاليا ولا دخلت في oop الي الان ,,,, سويلي الحذف وجزاك الله كل خير :)

Comment: على راسي، بسويلك الحذف وبشرحلك شوية حاجات بالكود، ع شان تستفيد منها لقدام برضو، وربنا يوفقك ويسعدك

Comment: @MostafaHossny شوف الرد إلي رديته عليك، وأي خدمة هيني موجود

Comment: This was an entertaining conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little explain, we start talking Arabic because Mostafa is not good in english, so i wrote a little explain in English and Arabic below to help to help both languages users.

```
while($row_img = mysqli_fetch_array($run_img)){

//explain [1]
    echo '
    <div style="width:200px; height:200px;  border: 5px solid red; margin:10px; float: right;">
        <img src="images/'.$row_img['c_img'].'" width="200" height="200" /><br />
        <form action="?" method="POST">
        <input name="id" value="'.$row_img['id'].'" hidden><!-- //explain [2] -->
        <input type="submit" name="delet" value="delet" />
        </form>
    </div>
    ';
}
if(isset($_POST['delet'])){
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);//explain [3]
    $delete= "DELETE FROM img WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $delete);
    if($query){
        echo 'Deleted Successfully!';
    }
}
```

> explain [1] Remove the query from inside while its bad to put it there
>
> explain [2] Then i made a hidden input called id to get the id from it
>
> explain [3] Make the hidden sent id to $id variable and intval it for more security, you can read about it

.

> explain [1] اول حاجة شلت الكويري إلي انت كاتبها جوا ال while
>
> explain [2] بعدين سويت زر مخفي مع كل صورة إسمه أي دي يعطينا الاي دي الخاص فيها
>
> explain [3] بعدين بستقبل الاي دي إلى بالزر المخفي على متغير جديد وبسويله شوية حماية.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: اولا شكرا جزيلا ليك على تعبك ومجهودك ثانيا مش ده مشكلتي  انا مشكلتي اني عملت صفحة اسمها 
 اندكس بضيقف عن طريقها الصور لقاعدة البيانات وبعدين عملت صفحة ثانية اسمها جت وظيفتها اني هعرض فيها الصور الي رفعتها على قاعدة البيانات طبعا لما اجي اعرض الصور الي جاية من قاعدة البيانات لازم استخدم while عشان تقوم بعرضهم جميعا 
تمام كده لحد هنا سهل وبسيط 
المشكلة ان انا عايز بقا تحت كل صورة زرار للحذف اذا قمت بالضغط علية يحذف فقط الصورة الي فوقة فقط وليس جميع الصور في الداتا بيز 
هيا ده المشكلة 
اتمنا اكون عرفت اوصلك المشكلة فين

Comment: مهو يا مصطفى الكود بعمل هيك، الامور تمام فش فيه مشكلة، جربه وردلي وقوللي إيش المشكلة في الكود؟؟؟

Comment: اسف يا زعيم الكود الي بعته تمام وزي الفل معلش مختش بالي من السطر الاول 
الكود شغال وتمام شكرا شكرا شكرا ليك :)

Comment: معلش بكرر اعتذاري الكود شغال وجزاك الله الف خير يا زعيم

Comment: لأ يخوي لا تعتذر ولا حاجة، مش مشكلة ع شان هيك قلتلك هيني موجود لأي خدمة ويا ريت لو بقدر اساعدك بحاجة ثانية، ولا شكر على الواجب

Answer (score 0):

Grab your `isset` and delete query out of `while`
Something like that. I did not checked all details but maybe it's good for inspiration.

```
$get_img = "SELECT * FROM img";
$run_img = mysqli_query($db, $get_img);

while ($row_img = mysqli_fetch_array($run_img))
{
  echo '<div>
          <img src="images/' . $row_pro['c_img'] . '" /><br />
        </div>';
}

echo '<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
      </form>'; 

if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  $delete= "DELETE FROM img WHERE id = :id", ['id'=>$row_pro['id']];
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $delete);
}
```

Hope you'll figured out.